# Why do I lose my edits after creating HDR raw files in Adobe CC Bridge ACR and enhancing them,

Tags: photo-editing, adobe-camera-raw, xmp

I'm a 20 year user of Photoshop and never had this happen before. After creating HDR raw files in Adobe CC Bridge ACR and enhancing them, I lost all of the edits after moving the files (note: the xmp files are still there).  I didn't even move them out of the folder, I just sorted the folder by "Type" so that all of the newly created HDR files would be put in one place and easily grabbed to move to a "selected folder" for image processing.  I've deleted Adobe Bridge and Photoshop and re-installed. I did a "Ctrl+Alt+Shift" to reset the preferences for Bridge and that didn't do anything.  I'm at a loss.  This has been happening to the last 6 projects I've edited and then I have to re-edit and not move them in anyway in order to process into jpegs.  Once I move them, the edits go away, but not all the edits. On some of the images, some remain.  Sometimes it happens to only part of the images that are edited. There is no rhyme or reason.  I don't know what else to do?

Comment: I'm sure this would be better addressed to Adobe.

Comment: Are the raw and sidecar files (.xmp or equivalent) in the same folder on the computer, and being copied together without renaming? It sounds like the software isn't finding all of the change instructions - your "edited" raw files will be two files : [raw + sidecar] until you export to .jpg, .png etc. Does this question help? https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/63649/editing-and-saving-raw-files-and-the-relationship-to-the-xmp-sidecar-files

Comment: I had a similar issue when using gradients in *Aftershot Pro*. It turned out that Aftershot updated the xmp information in the database but not in the sidecar xml file. The net result was that if the image was placed in a *catalog*, all edits were saved correctly to the catalog database but not the sidecar xml file. Directly editing the image without using a catalog lost all gradient changes. Check your sidecar xml file before and after your edits.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. Adobe told me to clear my cache, which didn't work.  I did two things that appeared to work, not sure which one did it. First, I deleted both Photoshop and Bridge, chose the option to not keep any preferences in case their was a hiccup in them, then restarted the pc. Second, under Camera Raw Preferences, DNG File Handling, I selected "Embed XMP in DNG", so that way the xmp files couldn't be somewhere else.  After doing that, my problem was gone.

Comment: notice that this might have a performance impact: every write to XMP will have to write the whole DNG. if you make batch edits to a bunch of files, this will be very noticeably slower.